# iOS: Writes to Realm in swift 1.2

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I'm trying to instantiate a realm to perform a write in Realm using the [given method in the docs](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#adding-objects):

```
let realm = try! Realm()
```

But I get the following error:

`Consecutive statements on a line must be separated must be separated by ';'`

Given that Realm is really built for Swift 2.0, I'm assuming the `try!` keyword isn't supported in Swift 1.2 (the version I'm using), but Realm states that it supports 1.2, but don't provide any documentation on how to do it in v 1.2.

Maybe I'm wrong that it's a swift version problem? Anyone know what the problem is? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to download the Swift 1.2 version available in [this branch](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/tree/swift-1.2).

Comment: Thanks, currently using the same swift version as before but changed line to simply `let realm = Realm()`. Probably won't upgrade until I run into a problem.

Comment: Well, for future development I think it's safe to say that refactoring your code to Swift 2.0 is inevitable.

Answer (score -1):

Please Follow the instructions.

Create a bridging header,

example,

1) Add a new Objective-C class to your xcode project.

2) Agree to have a bridging header created

3)Delete the Objective-C class

Add this in the bridging header:

```
#import "Realm/Realm.h"
```

Remove any Import Realm statements from your code, including from RLMSupport.swift
Now it should work. For example, I test with putting this in my ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class Person: RLMObject {
    dynamic var name = ""
    dynamic var birthdate = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1990: 1)
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let person = Person()
        person.name = "ANY_NAME"

        // Get the default Realm
        let realm = RLMRealm.defaultRealm()

        // Add to the Realm inside a transaction
        realm.beginWriteTransaction()
        realm.addObject(author)
        realm.commitWriteTransaction()

        // Print all Persons
        println(Person.allObjects())
    }
}
```

Output:

```
RLMArray <0x9a675890> (
[0] Person {
    name = ANY_NAME;
    birthdate = 1990-01-01 00:00:01 +0000;
}
)
```